# Is it safe to pass ID of db items as url parameters?

Tags: security, variables, url, frontend

Before publishing my work over the internet, I am here to ask you a debrief if what I built is sufficiently secure as accepted practice.

My client query a db by ID of items; then it passes the ID over the url to a second page.
So you will have something like:

```
 mypage.com/pagename?q=#numericID
```

The `#numericID` is the ID of an item. 
I wonder if the site is secure enough against crawling if the API are allowed under the same domain only, or if I should follow another practice more orthodox: cookies? re-factor the app as single page instead of two-pages - first for query, second for results? ...?

Please advice also how to re-frame my question, cause security about servers is completely a new thing to me and I don't know exactly what topic I should look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a numeric ID between two sites, it is possible for anybody to try other ID's on the 2nd site and see what they get. This is the same for any ID which is predictable.

Whether this is an issue is for you to determine, for example, a product site that just shows different products using the ID would probably be fine if an end user tried different ID's. Alternatively, if the ID was being used to define the currently logged in user then you would have a major problem.

The easy solution to the latter scenario is to use random ID's. For example [UUID's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which come in formats similar to

```
1176399b-0dfd-4bd1-9266-8d72abb90bd3
```

Assign a different UUID to each item you want to track and make sure both servers know what they are. It would be very hard for somebody to guess or crawl alternate UUID's. However a malicious end user may be able to learn them over time.

Beyond that the next step are 3D secure type systems where the UUID you pass to the 2nd server is one time only and subsequently verified between server 2 and server 1 on a secure channel.